# Using Iframe to present a webite- does not work

Tags: visualforce, iframe

Im working on a new service that uses Iframe to call some web application. but unfortentlly I don't have any luck, with iframe. according to the salesforce documentations, it says that they don't support Iframe anymore as a result of clickjacking. 
So my question: is there a way to use an Iframe in salesforce, to call a web service or just a site.

visual force page code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="SoftphoneSearchController_TEMP" docType="HTML">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->

<iframe height="600px" id="theIframe" name="theIframe" src="https://www.google.com" width="100%"></iframe> 

</apex:page>
```

error message:
'This content cannot be displayed in a frame'